How to determine which record was successful when deleting, updating, or adding a sobject Collection to a CompositeAPI sub-request?
I want to save the ID issued by salesforce to the corresponding record in the local DB. I also want to know how to determine which record failed.
Reasons below
In the case of new additions, the ID issued by salesforce is saved in the corresponding record in the local DB to ensure smooth updates and deletions from next time onwards.
Update/Delete Because we want to determine which records were successful or failed, and set the flag to false for successful records.
Steps

Send a request from the local DB to salesforce
For successful requests, the ID of the record on the salesforce side will be returned in the response → Save the ID returned in (2) in the corresponding record in the local DB I want to

I would like to delete, update, or add a sobject Collection by including it in a CompositeAPI subrequest as shown below.
{
// トランザクション化はしない
  "allOrNone": false,
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "DELETE",
      "url": "/services/data/v59.0/composite/sobjects?ids={カスタムオブジェクトID}",
      "referenceId": "deleteRef"
    },
    {
      "method": "PATCH",
      "url": "/services/data/v59.0/composite/sobjects",
      "referenceId": "updateRef",
      "body": {
        "records": [
          {
            "attributes": { "type": "Contact" },
                "Id": "12345asdfg",
                "LastName" : "hoge"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/services/data/v59.0/composite/sobjects",
      "referenceId": "insertRef",
      "body": {
        "records": [
          {
            "attributes": { "type": "Contact" },
            "LastName" : "hoge"
          },
          {
            "attributes": { "type": "Contact" },
            "LastName" : "hoge"
          },
          {
            "attributes": { "type": "Contact" },
            "LastName" : "hoge"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


Measures currently being considered

From reading the documentation, the order of requests and responses is basically the same. Since there is a description, I will judge based on the order.

Go to salesforce to get information based on the contents of the insert request


I currently think that method 2 will maintain consistency and make no mistakes when making new additions, but are there any other better methods?

このサイトは英語のみです。ご質問は翻訳してください。

For everyone else, I think y'all jumped on this one too quickly (and probably just based on mixing "Salesforce" into non-latin script). It's not spam and appears to be an honest question. It would certainly be ironic if some of the downvoters were the same people who interacted with this recent meta post.

All I did was pass the above through google translate. But yeah, clearly not spam.

As of this writing, this question doesn't show as for us as downvoted or upvoted.

Does this answer your question? How to optionally reference another request in a composite request?

@identigral It was at -4 when I made my comments, I assume mostly from being (incorrectly) flagged as spam and one downvote on top of that. You can click the little clock icon under the up/downvote buttons to get to a page that shows events. Showing the vote summaries gives a view into voting (granularity only goes to the "day" level).

@identigral Also, I think your suggested duplicate is a pretty poor match for the question being asked here. That, or you should go into more detail (as an answer, dangit!) about how one would use additional subrequests to determine success/failure in composited SObject Tree calls.

@DerekF The clock icon shows up 1, down 1. SE renders this as "no changes", fine.
